# Keras installation error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Anaconda, and I have already installed `TensorFlow` which works fine. Now I want to install `keras`. Here what i did:

```
activate tensorflow
pip install keras
```

installation seems to be successful. 
after that i run

```
idle
```

and then to test correctness, i run this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

and receive following error:

> Warning (from warnings module):
>     File "C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py__init__.py", line 36
>       from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
>   FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
>   Using TensorFlow backend.

I thought maybe this is just a warning, and then I run

```
jupyter notebook
```

and then try to import stuff. Error is this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.utils import np_utils

 ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4f6dad112f73> in <module>()
      5 from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
      6 
----> 7 from keras.models import Sequential
      8 from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
      9 from keras.utils import np_utils
> 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

**EDIT**
i've done cd to folder where I want to do my project.

```
print(sys.path)
```

in idle returns this:

> ```
> ['', 'C:\\Users\\smuminov\\Desktop\\UC\\Spring-2018\\CS504\\Project\\Prediction',
> ```
>
> 'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python35.zip',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\uritemplate-3.0.0-py3.5.egg']

in jupyter in returns this:

> ['',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python36.zip',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\DLLs',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions',
>   'C:\Users\smuminov\.ipython']

They are different. Should they be the same?

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.

Comment: is it actually an error, or just a warning?

Comment: per sascha and my comment: try ignoring it, and see if you can run a  simple "hello world" keras program

Comment: (Maybe) more [info](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/961).

Comment: Then I run jupyter notebook, and when i import same command there, i receive ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Comment: Have you tried `python -m pip install keras`?

Comment: Just tried, same warnings and errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably your python path is messed up.  The message you are getting in 'idle' is just a warning you can ignore it for now.  But the message you getting in your jupyter notebooks is a real error that you need to fix.

Try running the following code both in your idle environment and in Jupyter notebook.  Do it before you import Keras

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Then compare results.  Probably jupyter is not picking up your virtual environment.

**Continuing based on your test results**:

Looks like you running Idle from virtualenv that you created called 'tensorflow', but you are running jupyter from regular anaconda environment.

If you jupyter is simply installed as a module in Anaconda environmnet.  You can just install it again into your tensorflow virtual env by running the following commands

```
activate tensorflow
pip install jupyter
```

Then run

```
jupyter-notebook
```

This should fix your issue.  Make sure to print out sys.path to double check

Comment: I've made an edit to post with results. They are different. How can i fix that?

Comment: I've made edits to the answer based on your test results

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks